# int[] to BufferedImage

Tags: java, exception, int, bufferedimage, raster

I'm trying to filter a image. First, I put RGB values inside `int[][]` and then filter.
In the next step I have to convert `int[][]` to `int[]` and finally I would want to display the new image again. This is my code:

```
 int row,col,count=0;
          int[] pixels = new int[width*height];

            while(count!=(pixels.length)){   
                for(row=0;row<height;row++){
                     for(col=0;col<width;col++){
                         pixels[count] = imageArray[row][col];
                         count++;
                     }
                }
            }

             BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
             WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();

             raster.setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels); //The problem appear in this line
```

And this is my error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 181000
>       at java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.setPixels(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setPixels(Unknown Source)

I check that the types, the size of both arrays and I don't know what can I do.

The first array, int[][], is created with the next code:

```
int[][] imageArray = new int[height][width]; //...dar tamaño al array donde guardaremos la imagen

          for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) { //en este doble bucle vamos guardando cada pixel
             for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {

                imageArray[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);
                     }
                  }
```

Comment: Change the array declaration line to this `int[] pixels = new int[(width+1)*(height+1)];` , see if it works.

Comment: The documentation [ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setPixels(int, int, int, int, int[]) ] lists the following **two** reasons for this exception: **if the coordinates are not in bounds, or if the input int pixel array is too small to hold the input**

Comment: Thanks but I have just tried your idea and it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are zero based, therefore

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};
```

will have a length of 3, but a maximum element reference of 2 and

```
while( count <= array.length ) {
    System.out.println( array[count] );
    ++count;
}
```

will always overrun the array because the while doesn't fail until count is == array.length, or 3, and array[3] doesn't exist.

use `while( count < array.length )` instead

Comment: I tried your idea but I have the same problem. I'm going to show more code, because maybe the mistake isn't there. But I check every line and I can't understand why are happening.